# I need help with the proof of the scalar closure (from vector space) in a set of compact sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, compactness

I have a problem with the next proof. Sorry for my bad english, but this is not my language.

Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the power set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathfrak{C}\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\mathfrak{C}$ is the set of compact sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the next operations with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A,B\in\mathfrak{C}$:

$$A+B=A\cup B \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lambda A=\{\lambda x:x\in A\}$$

I need proof the properties of vector space with this operations. In the sum, four properties are true (the inverses doesn't exist). But, the problem is with the scalar closure. My idea is apply the definition with open covers, but, really, I don't know how.

Anyway, I thought that is not true, but, I can't find the counterexample.

Comment: If (additive) inverses don't exist then it can't be a linear space, can it? So why do you worry at all for scalar multiplication? Anyway, multiplication by scalar is a homeomorphism (you can get this also from the structure of topological group) so compactness remains.

Comment: In the exercise, I show which properties of vector space are true, i.e., if the asociativity of addition it's true, if the commutativity of addition it's true, if there exist an identity element of addition, etc. This is my problem, and the reason because I verify if the scalar closure are true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are asked to check all defining properties in the definition of a vector spaces and see which one are false and which one are true.

And I guess your problem is to verify the following:

$\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \in \mathfrak{C}$ $\quad \Rightarrow \quad \lambda \cdot A \in \mathfrak{C}$ ?

If so, then the answer was already in the comment by @DonAntonio:

(I assume you work with the euclidean topology) If you write $\lambda \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $x \mapsto \lambda x$, then your *scalar multiplication* on $\mathfrak{C}$, $\lambda \cdot A$, is just the image of $A$ under the *map* $\lambda$, i.e $\lambda \cdot A = \lambda(A)$. But it is easy to show (first year proof I guess in an undergraduate analysis course) that the map $\lambda$ is countinuous (even a homeomorphism if $\lambda \neq 0$). And again it is a short proof to show that continuous maps map compact sets to compact sets. So since $A$ is compact so is $\lambda(A)=\lambda \cdot A$.

Comment: Your proof is so good, thanks. Really. But, the only problem is that actually I am not studying analysis, but I know some properties and results of analysis. My course is of multivariable calculus. And the next theme is exactly functions. Now, we study the topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And, I don't know if I can use this to proof that's. Wathever, if I can't find another proof, I think that I'll use this.

Comment: But even if you only have the definition of a *continuous map* and of a *compact set* you should be able to prove these two assertions you need, i.e. that "$\lambda$ is continuous" and "continuous images of compact sets are compact".

Comment: I wiil do it. Thanks.